# PowerShell Connect-VIServer with multiple potential credentials

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am work in a data center and am currently working on creating a script that will connect to multiple esx hosts.  Unfortunately, the username/passwords are mostly the same but some of them are different.  I want to check for a failed connection, and then retry with another set of credentials.  I've got three or four different sets that I need to try before I let the host be listed as not accessible.

Currently, I have my script successfully connecting using the most common credentials without any problem.  Now I want to upgrade the script to be able to test all of the possible credentials if it fails with the main one.

In my research to find a solution, I came across try/catch but I'm thinking that is going to get pretty nasty with three or four possible layers of repeated commands.

So here is what I have so far with a try/catch idea going:

```
$goodhost | ForEach-Object { 
    try {  
        $sessions = @(Connect-VIServer -Server $_ -User 'user' -Password $psw - 
        ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
    } 
    catch { 
        if ($Error[0] -ccontains "incorrect user name") { 
            $sessions = @(Connect-VIServer -Server $_ -User 'user1' -Password $psw1 
            -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
        } 
     } 
}
```

My current thought is, that to do a try/catch for three different possible username/password pairs, would basically require me to do 3 nested repeats of this same thing.  In otherwords, the following:

```
connect using main credential
if fail
  Connect using second credential
  if fail
     connect using third credential
     if fail
        connect using fourth credential
```

I guess my question is, is this the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Hi chwnelson, welcome to SO. For us to be able to help you with your question, you first need to help us understand you question by providing more detail which may come in the forms of providing your code and attempts so far and giving us more insight to what the issues may be! Please edit your question to help us help you!

Comment: SO is not a code writing site and without your code and/or attempts, this question isn't suitable here! Try editing your question to add more detail and more suitable for this site or try posting this on a different site! See [What shouldn't I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use a dictionary that have username passwords and loop through it until your connection is successful

Comment: @Jawad Thanks for the response.  This idea had a lot of promise and looked like it would work.  Unfortunately, realized that the username was going to be a problem since it repeats on all of the credentials.  Instead I'm going to use an array and just call for a specific item inside the array.  Your answer helped me solve my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Jawad provided the insight I was looking for.  While a dictionary won't work in this case it was close enough that I feel his suggestion lead me to the solution.  I will edit this once I have finished writing the new code.